# How to set Java ProcessBuilder parameter to run external .java file?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to run other java file using `ProcessBuilder` class.

I would like to get input of entire path of java file + file name + *.java* and compile it.

Example, input: `C:\Windows\test.java`

And then, I store input into `String` variable `FILE_LOCATION` and call `processbuilder` to compile input *.java* file.

Here is my code:

```
 static String JAVA_FILE_LOCATION;
 static String command[] = {"javac", JAVA_FILE_LOCATION};
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
 Process process = processBuilder.start();
 process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"java","-cp",A,B}).start();
```

But I don't know how to set the parameters.

```
process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{
"java","-cp",A,B}).start();
```

How should I set that parameter `(A, B)`?

Comment: You can call java compiler without necessarily relying on running an external process, by using a `javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your exact question, let's say, for instance, your class is in package `com.yourcompany.yourproduct` and your class file is in `/dir/to/your/classes/com/yourcompany/yourproduct/Yourclass.c‌​lass.`

Then `A = "/dir/to/your/classes"` and `B = "com.yourcompany.yourproduct.Yourclass"`.

However, there's a few things to be aware of. Looking at your code:

```
static String JAVA_FILE_LOCATION;
static String command[] = {"javac", JAVA_FILE_LOCATION};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

No. You need to CD to the directory and *then* run `javac`. The easiest way to do that is by calling `processBuilder.directory(new File("/dir/to/your/classes"))`. Then you need to give `javac` a relative path to your source file (`"com/yourcompany/yourproduct/Yourclass.java"`).

```
Process process = processBuilder.start();
process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"java","-cp",A,B}).start();
```

Wait until the first process has finished compiling before you try to run it! Between the two lines above, insert `process.waitFor();`. You might also want to check for any errors and only run the second process if the first has succeeded.

By the way, there's no need for all that long-hand creation of string arrays. Just use varargs: `process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", A, B).start();`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.